# Android: Obtaining the height of my TabHost

Tags: android

I'm attempting to distribute the heights of my listview rows evenly to fit the dimensions of my screen, however I'm working off of the screen resolution, which does not take into account the tabhost height.

I'm wondering how I would get the dimensions of my tabhost.

Answer (score 0):

If by the "dimensions", you mean the width and height, you can use `yourTabHostInstance.getWidth` and `yourTabHostInstance.getHeight` to retrieve them. There are other methods available for finding out more specific View properties as well (see [Tabhost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) for more information, particularly the methods inherited from android.view.View).

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Android graphics pipeline, but if it's anything like WPF, you may have to wait until the screen's been rendered before you call the getHeight and getWidth methods, though I'm not sure hwo you'd do that.

Another option would be to call `yourTabHostInstance.getLayoutParams()` and then get the height from there, though this may still return 0 until the view has been rendered.